# Applying rvest pipes to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I've got a dataframe called base_table with a lot of 311 data and URLs that point to a broader description of each call.

I'm trying to create a new variable called case_desc with a series of rvest functions each URL.

```
base_table$case_desc <- 
                      read_html(base_table$case_url) %>%
                           html_nodes("rc_descrlong") %>%
                           html_text()
```

But this doesn't work for I suppose obvious reasons that I can't muster right now. I've tried playing around with functions, but can't seem to nail the right format.

Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because `read_html` doesn't work with a vector of URLs. It will throw an error if you give it a vector...

`> read_html(c("http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com"))
Error: expecting a single value`

You probably have to use an `apply` function...

```
library("rvest")
base_table$case_desc <- sapply(base_table$case_url, function(x)
                          read_html(x) %>%
                            html_nodes("rc_descrlong") %>%
                            html_text())
```